# NetBeans: Context-Aware Action with Subfolder?

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, rcp

I'm creating a NetBeans plugin, and would like the `Action`s I declare to appear grouped together in their own submenu when right-clicking on a Java file.  I'm able to get the `Action` to appear within the context menu, however I am unable to put it into a submenu.  My current `Action` annotations look like this...

```
@ActionID(
        category = "Source",
        id = "net.myproj.actions.DoMyAction"
)
@ActionRegistration(
        displayName = "#CTL_DoMyAction"
)
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Loaders/text/x-java/Actions", position = 2950, separatorBefore = 2925, separatorAfter = 2975),
    @ActionReference(path = "Editors/text/x-java/Popup", position = 2950, separatorBefore = 2925, separatorAfter = 2975)
})
@Messages("CTL_DoMyAction=Foo...")
```

I've tried adding another path under `Loaders/text/x-java/Actions`, but that doesn't work.  Same with `Editors/text/x-java/Popup`.  Is there a way that I could have my `Action`s grouped together within their own separate submenu?